# ansible install issue using python3 pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, ansible

Seeing issue locating installed Ansible package.

Following along

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/installation_guide/intro_installation.html

Tried running commands as per above link & below is what I got in the environment.

```
$ python3 -m pip -V
pip 9.0.3 from /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages (python 3.6)
```

And installation of package just looks ok on `python3 -m pip install --user ansible` as well & output shows like below:

```
$ python3 -m pip show ansible
Name: ansible
Version: 4.10.0
Summary: Radically simple IT automation
Home-page: https://ansible.com/
Author: Ansible, Inc.
Author-email: info@ansible.com
License: GPLv3+
Location: /home/ansible/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Requires: ansible-core
```

But when I run below, its not able to find in PATH

```
ansible --version
bash: /bin/ansible: No such file or directory
```

Does pip3 packages needs to be referenced in different way to access Ansible pacakge?. Don't see anything under `/bin/ansible` or `/usr/bin/ansible`

Comment: From the Ansible tag description: _On-topic questions are concerned with the use of the tool itself. **Installing Ansible** and prerequisites, connection issues, ... **are off-topic**._

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you installed Ansible by running, as a non-root user:

```
python3 -m pip install --user ansible
```

Then Ansible wasn't installed into `/bin`. On a Linux system, it would probably end up in `$HOME/.local/bin`, which would need to be in your `$PATH` in order to the shell to find it when you type `ansible` on the command line.

You can temporarily update your path by running:

```
PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
```

To permanently update your `$PATH`, you would need to modify your shell's initialization files. If you're using Bash, that's going to be `$HOME/.profile` or `$HOME/.bash_profile`, whichever exists.

Comment: Thank you. 2 questions : 1. As it will be user specific `./local` dir bin location, how other user can reference `ansible` installed software?. 2. Looks like even with `.bash_profile` holding line `PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/bin` some how it is not getting sourced for user with which `ansible` is installed with & explicit `source ~/.bash_profile` is needed. Any way we can avoid it?. Even switch user with `-` is not working on locating `ansible`directly

Comment: w/r/t your first question: if you want to share Ansible across multiple users, don't install it into a user home directory. w/r/t your second question: Are you certain that Bash is your shell? Have you tried logging out and logging back in? Are you certain that you're not overriding `$PATH` somewhere (e.g. in your `.bashrc`)? If you're having a hard time setting `$PATH`, you may want to open a new question and provide detailed answers to all of those questions; the comments here aren't really the right place for an extended diagnosis.

Answer (score 0):

PATH needs to be set/referenced by sourcing .bash_profile explicitly.

This solved the problem!.

As with `--user` it creates `.local/` site-packages lib.

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/bin
```

Comment: That appears to be exactly what I said in my answer.